# OpenCV Android Histogram equalization reducing the range of intensities

Tags: android, opencv

In my android project I am using OpenCV 2.4.8 and the function Imgproc.equalizeHist gives me strange results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQENQ.jpg

First shows the original image, second is what I get in android, and third is what I expected (made with imageJ from the original using Process->Enhance Contrast).

Code:

```
Imgproc.equalizeHist(imageROI, imageROI); //src, dst  
imageROI is CvType.CV_8UC1.
```

Am I supposed to  do something with imageROI before calling equalize? OpenCV documentation is mostly C/C++, so i don't know if anything is different for java on android.
Any help would be welcome!

Comment: This is my first question so sorry for rookie mistakes!

Comment: CvType.CV_8UC1 looks correct. please add the exception you get to your question.

Comment: Looks like he's not getting an exception, it's just not doing what he expected.  Looks like it's reducing the range of intensities instead of expanding them.